# Make program to not count if Numbers are different than {-1,1,2,-2}

Tags: c

I'm really having a difficult time to make my counter to not count if the numbers are different than {1,-1,-2,-2}.

Here is what I'm trying to do:

```
if(n == 1 || -1 || 2 || -2){
cont++;

    }
else{

}
```

But it's not working, the program continues to count even when the numbers are different than those above.

Here is the entire code:

```
int main(void){
int n,pri,ult,dir,esq,cima,baixo;
int cont = 0;
int soma = 0;
scanf("%d", &n);

while (n != 0){

soma = cont;
if (n == 1)
{
    dir = n;
}
if (n == -1)
{
    esq = n ;
}
if (n == 2){
    cima = n;
}
if (n == -2)
{
    baixo = n;
}

if(cont == 1)
    {
    pri = n;
    }
    if(n == 1 || -1 || 2 || -2){
cont++;

    }
else{

}

ult = n;
scanf("%d", &n);

    }
printf("cont %d\n", cont);
if (soma == 0){
    printf("O veiculo fez um caminho fechado");
}
else{
    printf("O veiculo fez um caminho aberto");
}
}
```

Comment: regarding this line: `if(n == 1 || -1 || 2 || -2){`   C cannot do implied target 'if' statements.   The line needs to be: `if( n==1 || n==-1 || n==2 || n==-2 ){`

Answer (score 4):

No, chaining of logical OR operators (`||`) is not possible. You need to check each one of them individually. Change

```
 if(n == 1 || -1 || 2 || -2)
```

to

```
if(n == 1 || n == -1 || n ==  2 || n == -2)
```

Otherwise, due to left-to-right evaluation rule (associativity), what you're end up getting is

```
if ( (n == 1) || -1 || 2 || -2)
```

which is same as either

```
if( 0 || -1 || 2 || -2)
```

or

```
if( 1 || -1 || 2 || -2)
```

both of which yields `1` as result as the other operands of `||` are non-zero (TRUE).